# converting 2d string array to 2d integer array

Tags: java

I keep on getting a null pointer exception and I have no idea why. Explain please.

```
public static int[][] convertStringToInt(String[][] array){

    int [][] numbers = new int [array.length][];
    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        numbers[row] = new int [array[row].length];                //line 48
        for(int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
        {
            numbers[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(array[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}



public static void main (String[] agrs)
{

    File selectedFile = selectFile("Enter fileName for double number, EX:    
                      decimalNumbers.csv");
    if( !selectedFile.exists())
    {
       System.out.print("\nFile does not exit, program terminating\n\n");
       System.exit(1);
    }

    int countLines = countLinesInFile(selectedFile);
    String cities [][] = loadArrayFromFile(selectedFile, countLines);

    int [][] unitsSold = convertStringToInt(cities); //line 157

    System.out.println(unitsSold);
 }
```

here are the errors when i enter the file name

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at labReview.ArrayOfArrays.convertStringToInt(ArrayOfArrays.java:48)
at labReview.ArrayOfArrays.main(ArrayOfArrays.java:157)
```

Comment: This works fine for me, can you give an input example where the error occurs?

Comment: I don't understand this: `int [][] numbers = new int [array.length][];` ... the second dimension isn't specified.

Comment: It's not necessary to specify second dimension in 2D arrays. Try googling it.

Comment: That suggests that `array[row]` is `null` for some row.

Comment: Try printing your `cities` variable before passing it to the converter. Or even better, debug.

Comment: It must be the particular row in which the string is `null`. Check your `CSV` file.

Comment: You have a `null` in your `String[][]` and try to use it via `array[row].length`

Answer (score 1):

The method `convertStringToInt` works fine. The exception you described `NullPointerException` may occur in the line

```
numbers[row] = new int[array[row].length];
```

if `array[row]` is `null`. So the error may be occuring because the method `loadArrayFromFile` is returning a `null` row, like this (for example):

```
String[][] s = { { "1", "2", "3" }, { "1" }, null, { "3", "4" } };
```

Print the elements in the array returned by the method `loadArrayFromFile` to see if there are `null` rows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have a null array in your cities at some index.

```
String cities [][] = loadArrayFromFile(selectedFile, countLines);
```

Try printing your cities array as below

```
for(String[] cityArr : cities){
 System.out.println("Cities at Index "+i+" is : "+citiArr);
}
```

And if you see a "null" value at any index, then modify your loadArrayFromFile to replace a black array whenever you have a null while adding it to cities array.

```
....

if(citiArr==null){
 citiArr = new String[]{};
}
cities[i][j]=citiArr;

....
```